# getting info with MySQL or PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble displaying my league standings correctly.
I have a CSV file with all teams divided by Divisions and Conferences
(basically trying to display my standings like the NHL standings)

The top 3 teams of each division are displayed
then the top 2 teams in the conference that are not in the top 3 of divisions are displayed.

Here is the code I have now

```
//Query Central //
$QueryCentral="SELECT * FROM QNHLProTeamV2 WHERE Division='$CentralDivision' ORDER by Points DESC, GP ASC, W DESC, GoalDiff DESC LIMIT 3";
$ResultCentral=mysql_query($QueryCentral);
$NumCentral=mysql_num_rows($ResultCentral);

//Query Pacific //
$QueryPacific="SELECT * FROM QNHLProTeamV2 WHERE Division='$PacificDivision' ORDER by Points DESC, GP ASC, W DESC, GoalDiff DESC LIMIT 3";
$ResultPacific=mysql_query($QueryPacific);
$NumPacific=mysql_num_rows($ResultPacific);

//Query West Wild Card //
$QueryWestWildCard="SELECT * FROM QNHLProTeamV2 WHERE Conference='$WesternConference' ORDER by Points DESC, GP ASC, W DESC, GoalDiff DESC LIMIT 6,20";
$ResultWestWildCard=mysql_query($QueryWestWildCard);
$NumWestWildCard=mysql_num_rows($ResultWestWildCard);
```

The first 2 queries work and I do get the top 3 of each division
but for the Wild Card I could only figure out how to get all the teams in order without
top 6. 
How can I display the teams that are NOT in top 3 of divisions?

Comment: You could get a list of the top 3 of each division and then on the final query use a "NOT IN" command and list out all of the top 3 of each division.

Comment: could I have a example of the code I would need to use ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that should do the trick  You will need to update the $row["TeamName"] with the actual column's name, however.

```
//Query Central //
$QueryCentral="SELECT * FROM QNHLProTeamV2 WHERE Division='$CentralDivision' ORDER by Points DESC, GP ASC, W DESC, GoalDiff DESC LIMIT 3";
$ResultCentral=mysql_query($QueryCentral);
$NumCentral=mysql_num_rows($ResultCentral);
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ResultCentral);
{
    $top[$i]="\"".$row["TeamName"]."\"";
    $i++;
}

//Query Pacific //
$QueryPacific="SELECT * FROM QNHLProTeamV2 WHERE Division='$PacificDivision' ORDER by Points DESC, GP ASC, W DESC, GoalDiff DESC LIMIT 3";
$ResultPacific=mysql_query($QueryPacific);
$NumPacific=mysql_num_rows($ResultPacific);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ResultPacific);
{
    $top[$i]="\"".$row["TeamName"]."\"";
    $i++;
}

//Generate list - delimited by comma
$toplist = implode(",", $top);

//Query West Wild Card //
$QueryWestWildCard="SELECT * FROM QNHLProTeamV2 WHERE Conference='$WesternConference' and NOT IN ($toplist) ORDER by Points DESC, GP ASC, W DESC, GoalDiff DESC LIMIT 3";
$ResultWestWildCard=mysql_query($QueryWestWildCard);
$NumWestWildCard=mysql_num_rows($ResultWestWildCard);
```

Or, you could use this query for the wild card (looks messier):

```
$QueryWestWildCard="SELECT * FROM QNHLProTeamV2 
WHERE Conference='$WesternConference' 
and NOT IN (SELECT TeamName FROM QNHLProTeamV2 WHERE Division='$CentralDivision' ORDER by Points DESC, GP ASC, W DESC, GoalDiff DESC LIMIT 3) 
AND NOT IN (SELECT TeamName FROM QNHLProTeamV2 WHERE Division='$PacificDivision' ORDER by Points DESC, GP ASC, W DESC, GoalDiff DESC LIMIT 3) 
ORDER by Points DESC, GP ASC, W DESC, GoalDiff DESC LIMIT 3";
```

Comment: I understand the messier code..
but it doesn't work. I changed the "TeamName" for what it actually is in the database but all I get is this error

Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/content/38/9929738/html/QNHLScript/QNHL-ClassementWCtest.php on line 95

Comment: make sure that your column names match what is in the query.  It is case sensitive.

Comment: Is there any way you can post your database schema or a link to an sqlfiddle with your database?

Comment: Also PHP MySQL queries might not be able to do multiple queries in one query.  So,try my first code too

Comment: My first code is basically the same as the second code, but it generates a comma separated list of conferences and divisions

Comment: is there a way to get in contact (email,skype,icq) where I could show the whole code and hopefully find a solution ?